# MS SQL Add New Login username for Windows Authentication doesn't work with FQDN

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am just wondering why when adding a new Login, I cannot use the FQDN\username
e.g. "muse.local\jsmith"

I have to instead use instead "MUSE\jsmith"? What is the difference please? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation is quite clear on this, you must use the pre-2000 domain name, which is not the fqdn nor a upn.

```
When you are creating logins that are mapped from a Windows domain 
account, you must use the pre-Windows 2000 user logon name in the 
format [<domainName>\<login_name>].
```